# Possible reasons for java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0

Tags: java, sockets, jdbc, tcp

I have my application war file hosted and running on Tomcat which had been in a good state for several months now. There has been no recent changes to the Tomcat configuration or any other environment related change like the Java version on the machine or the war file itself. Also, there has been no sudden or rapid increase in the load on the server as it is an isolated environment.

Just over the last few days, the calls from the client to the server hangs up the client and the trace on the server shows,

```
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1525)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:3274)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:4433)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:386)
```

Yes, there can be an implementation for Read Timeout to prevent the hang which will result in Socket Timeout Exception and prevent the hang of the client. But the question arises, what are all the possible **reasons** causing **Socket Read to wait indefinitely** ?

I tried adding the Read Timeout which causes a huge number of exceptions at the client end and causes failures. Any help on what are the reasons for the **Socket Read not to return** and wait indefinitely?

Comment: any update on this, encountering the same error with tomcat 9.0.5, jdk 1.8_201,found the problem using visual vm

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Tomcat. The DBMS is not responding. You should certainly use read timeouts, but make them long enough not to be intrusive. Check your database server.

Answer (score 3):

> But the question arises, what are all the possible reasons causing Socket Read to wait indefinitely?

The only plausible reasons for a socket read to block are:

1. The remote server hasn't written the the data that the client is trying to read.
2. A networking problem blocking client / server communication.

---

In this case, the most likely explanation was that your database server was offline or stuck.